# return vector from servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, vector

I have to do an HTML page with 2 text boxes, one for name and the other one for ammount, then theres a widget that let me choose which type of account im creating, savings or checking, then a send button, this information is going to be sent to the servlet. The servlet have to create an object depending on the type of account, then save it on a `Vector`, then the servlet need to respond an HTML textarea with the information thats on the `Vector`, and the same widgets that were in the first page so you can insert another account, when you insert another one you have to send the information to the same servlet, and then do the same work. But in the HTML text area must appear the first account and the one that I just created, and so on and on.

The thing is that I can do all of this but what I can't do is the showing all the information of the vector for some reason I just get the account that I just created in the text area.

Here's the servlet code. Note, the `toString()` returns all of the info thats stored on the `Vector`, and `addAccount()` adds the account to the `Vector`.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletPrincipal extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String nombre = request.getParameter("nom");
        String monto = request.getParameter("mon");
        String tipo = request.getParameter("fgcghch");


        double montoi = Double.parseDouble(monto);
String a="ah";
String b="che";

AccountsLedger objeto = new AccountsLedger();

if(a.equals(tipo)){

    SavingsAccount cnt1= new SavingsAccount(nombre, montoi, 2);

    objeto.addAccount(cnt1);

    objeto.toString();
    out.println("<textarea rows='20' cols='20'>"+objeto.toString()+"</textarea>");
    out.print("<form action='ServletPrincipal' method='post'><input type='text' name='nom'><input type='text' name='mon'>");
    out.println("<select name='fgcghch'><option value='ah'>Ahorro</option><option value='che'>Cheque</option></select>");
    out.println("<input type='submit' name='boton'></form>");
    }
if(b.equals(tipo)){


CheckingAccount cnt= new CheckingAccount(nombre, montoi);



objeto.addAccount(cnt);
String y = objeto.toString();
out.println("<textarea rows='2' cols='20'>"+y+"</textarea>");
    out.print("<form action='ServletPrincipal' method='post'><input type='text' name='nom'><input type='text' name='mon'>");
    out.println("<select name='fgcghch'><option value='ah'>Ahorro</option><option value='che'>Cheque</option></select>");
    out.println("<input type='submit' name='boton'></form>");


}




    }
}
```

Comment: I .. am .. lost .. The code also doesn't really help much since it is not self-documenting. Any chance to clarify the **functional requirement**?

Comment: it needs to save accounts information, the vector can save checking accounts, and savings accounts.
first theres a html page, with the widgets I specified at the beginning, then that info is sent to the servlet, (the servlet thats over there) and it has to create the object, and save it, then return a html page with the information that the method toString() returns, and the same widgets that i mentioned in the beginning, so i can insert another account, and then return the info of the first account and the one that i just created

Comment: i know is not the best explanation, but im really tired, and i can keep my eyes barely open.

Comment: @david: perhaps you should come back then when you've slept. You are expecting help here, so not asking the question as good as possible can be considered disrespectful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use Vector, use ArrayList. It works the same but does not used synchronized keywords on the methods which is actually a good thing for performance. It is very rare indeed that two threads will access an array and if they did the synchronized keyword is pretty useless anyway for a collection class.

Second, consider if you want to write a servlet here or whether a JSP would be better. A JSP is basically an inside out servlet so if there is more HTML than Java it makes sense.

Thirdly, to iterate an ArrayList with modern Java is trivial, so if the intent is to create a string to insert into HTML, then it can be done like this:

```
ArrayList<String> values = // ... built somewhere
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String v : values) {
  sb.append(v);
}
out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I'd love to give you +3 for all three paragraphs, but alas, I can't (+1)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, you need to hold the `objeto` for more than one request. Now, you create a new one for every request. Do **not** use a member of the servlet for this (servlets need to be stateless), but you can use the session.

Instead of

```
AccountsLedger objeto = new AccountsLedger();
```

use

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
AccountsLedger objeto = (AccountsLedger)session.getAttribute("objeto");
if (objeto == null) {
  objeto = new AccountsLedger();
  session.setAttribute("objeto", objeto);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you had to do is create the object accountledget before the doPost method

Comment: First: this is not some leet #irc channel. Please use real language. Second: 'I' is probably what you meant instead of 'u', after all it was your problem, not ours.

Comment: Yes, but where? Have a look at my answer.

Comment: well then I'm sorry, you don't have to be rude.